# Does DP-DLDVI Converter removes HDCP?

Tags: dvi, displayport, hdcp

I'm using an old 2560x1600 monitor that doesn't have HDCP chip and only accepts DVI dual link input. ( Precisely, the part number of the panel is lm300w01-sta1 )

And I'm considering to upgrade my graphics card to RTX2080.

However, In my country, there are no RTX2080 cards having DVI output ports, only having DPs and HDMIs.

I know there are several DP to DL-DVI active converters around $50-$100. However, I'm not sure whether do they decrypt HDCP or not.

In summary, can I use DP-DLDVI converter such as apple or bizlink active converter with HDCP-incompliant dual-link only monitor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the receiving device doesn't support HDCP then the display connection to it will not be encrypted at all.

The result will be that the monitor will work with your graphics card, but any programs that require HDCP such as Blu-ray players or online video streaming sites will know and act as they believe appropriate.

What this means is that your display will be fine for "normal" use but protected media will either refuse to play or play at degraded quality depending on the software.

Some online streaming site such as Netflix or Flixter will work, but will only stream SD rather than HD or 4K content. Blu-ray playback will depend on your software.